# Automake: Add extension to default clean target

Tags: autotools, automake

With the way my project is currently configured with autotools, when I compile my library, my source files all generate the standard `.o` and `.lo` files, but they also generate `.gcno` extensions. When I use `make clean`, the first two extensions are cleaned up in all of my source directories, but the `.gcno` files are still around. I know there's probably a simple Automake variable that I need to set, but I can't find it in any documentation (probably don't know what to search for). Can anyone give me a hint where I should look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just list the files in CLEANFILES:

```
CLEANFILES = foo.gcno bar.gcno ...
```

That requires an explicit list of files.  It might be easier to add a clean-local hook to Makefile.am:

```
clean-local:
        rm -f *.gcno
```

There are several clean hooks.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html

Comment: Is there any way to set this at the top level Makefile.am and have it apply to all of the subdirectories as well? I should have mentioned this at the beginning. I'm trying to avoid having to add this to every Makefile in the project.

Comment: You can specify relative paths in CLEANFILES in the toplevel:  `CLEANFILES = /p/a/t/h/foo.gcno`, or build a script that does a recursive descent and call it from the clean-local hook.  (Make sure to distribute that script!)

Comment: So, no is the short answer then. :)

Comment: I think the short answer is 'yes'.  The script described above is trivial: `find . -name '*.gcno' -exec rm {} \;` (avoid -delete since I'm not sure it's portable).  Then toplevel Makefile.am gets DISTFILES=script.name and a clean-local hook.  Or, just put that one liner in the clean-local hook directly.  The draw back to this is that the gcno files will not be deleted if someone does a make clean in a subdirectory.